# How to strip out part of a URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect from this:

```
www.mysite.com/product.html?item=example
```

to:

```
www.mysite.com/example
```

I have this rewrite rule in my .htaccess file but it isn't working:

```
RewriteRule ^/product\.html\?item=(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Here's what I have now:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^item=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/product\.html$ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

And here is the Final result after I got rid of forward slash at the beginning of the rule and added a question mark at the end of the rule to get rid of the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^item=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^product\.html$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You can't put the query string on the LHS of the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are in an `.htaccess` file, you'll want to remove the leading slash from your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^item=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^product\.html$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

In reference to the query string being passed through, the [Apache 2.2 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) for [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) says this about it:

> **Modifying the Query String**
>
> By default, the query string is passed
>   through unchanged. You can, however,
>   create URLs in the substitution string
>   containing a query string part. Simply
>   use a question mark inside the
>   substitution string to indicate that
>   the following text should be
>   re-injected into the query string.
>   When you want to erase an existing
>   query string, end the substitution
>   string with just a question mark. To
>   combine new and old query strings, use
>   the `[QSA]` flag.

So as you discovered, you need only to add a `?` after the substitution.

Comment: Thank you that worked great.  The only problem now is that the url has the query string appended at the end so it now looks like this: www.mysite.com/example?item=example  How do I get rid of the query string from the end?

Comment: Figured it out. Just needed to add a ? to the end of the rewrite rule: RewriteRule ^product\.html$ /%1? [R=301,L]