# How do I strip part of a url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How do I strip a part of the url? I do not know much about htaccess or apache.

I would like to strip `www.mysite.com/page=services` to `www.mysite.com/services` for example.

What exactly do I need to put in the .htaccess file in order to achieve this, and would that work for other pages as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know regex?
You should read about mod_rewrite and make sure you have it enabled on your server. http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-basic-examples.html

Comment: I believe you mean you want *rewrite* a prettier URL of `/services` to `index.php?page=services`, correct?

Comment: No it is not correct, I want it the other way around. I have mod rewrite enabled, I know some regex but not how to remove 'page=' from the url in htaccess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to strip out part of a URL with mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473826/how-to-strip-out-part-of-a-url-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this for one of my sites lately and came up with this and for me it works fine,

this goes into the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

then if you would write yoursite.com/pagename it would send yoursite.com/index.php?page=pagename to your php.
You will link to the page like so: yoursite.com/pagename
it wont change yoursite.com/index.php?page=pagename to yoursite.com/pagename in the adress bar after you send it.(if that makes sense :) )

I hope this is what you are looking for...

Comment: I do not understand everything you said, I just hope this removes part of the url i need removed :) I'll check it on my live server in a bit and get back to you. I really hope this does it. I'll get back to you in a couple of hours hopefully.

Comment: well you will still need to change the links in the db to say yoursite.com/pagename so the users sees this link in the address bar but htaccess will redirect this request to yoursite.com/index.php?page=pagename so php can figure out what to do. (user will still see yoursite.com/pagename while this happens in the background)

Comment: I changed the url in the DB to yoursite.com/pagename but yoursite.com/index.php?page=pagename is not happening in the background, it just links to mysite.com/pagename which doesn't really exist so it stays on the home page basically. pagename is a variable it should dyamically get for each page.

Comment: IT WORKS! I had some other stuff in the .htaccess file, i deleted that and also added 0-9 in the expression (coz i have numbers as well) and it works now! THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean your original URL to be `www.mysite.com/index.php?page=services` and not `www.mysite.com/page=services`

Also, you probably mean the opposite, you should switch `www.mysite.com/services` to `www.mysite.com/index.php?page=service`

Anyway, to change `www.mysite.com/services` to `www.mysite.com/index.php?page=services` then you need .htaccess, and the rule for that would be `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]`

As suggested earlier, you should read about .htaccess, regex, and rewrite rules. Best resource is the apache documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

I read your comment earlier that you need the opposite, I am not sure why you need that, because the whole idea of URL shortining is to make easy-to-remember URLs in addition to some security concerns that can be resolved. The URL is the first thing that is sent to load your webpage, then .htaccess changes it to some form undrstandable by PHP then PHP deals with get parameters for example.

Comment: I mean what I said and not the opposite. Why would u think I mean the opposite, and why would I want to turn a normal url to index.pgp?page=services? I want what I asked, to turn www.mysite.com/page=something to www.mysite.com/something

Comment: I added a comment to my answer that answers your question. Anyway, here is how it goes. First you write a URL that is easy to remember, such as `www.mysite.com/services` then .htaccess changes that to something like this `www.mysite.com/index.php?page=services` HOWEVER, that new URL is not re-written on the address bar (unless you want it to), and then .htaccess sends that new URL to PHP which should handle the $_GET Parameter for you.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. I have put it simply yet you don't understand. I am pulling content dynamically from a DB and so I get pages like mysite.com/index.php?page=something, and I want to change it to mysite.com/something . I do not see where you posted an answer for that, you posted something that does the opposite of what I want.

Comment: Easy tiger, no need to be upest. Have you thought of using PHP instead of .htaccess, you are pulling information from the database (and I am assuming through PHP, otherwise you can use any language you want), but in anycase all you need is a string manupilation function that will do that for you. It is easier than .htaccess

Comment: I am not upset and I do appreciate you trying to help, but exactly due to the fact you're taking your time to help me I would like to get a good answer. I am also making pages dynamically so I think I do need htaccess. (and yes I am using php). Can you just tell me if it is possible to remove 'index.php?page=' from the url and how to do that in .htaccess?

Comment: OK, can I ask you something? I like to know what you need to do. You are pulling this URL www.mysite.com/index.php?page=service from the database, right? Then can I ask why are you trying to use .htaccess to convert it to this new URL www.mysite.com/services ?  Are you willing to reuse the new URL again? Are you willing to save it back to the database? What is it exactly you are trying to achieve with the new URL? The reason for this question is this does help in answering you correctly.

Comment: Yes I am pulling all the URLs from the DB. I am trying to use .htaccess because I do not know a better way. Right now i have urls like this: mysite.com/index.php?page=1, mysite.com/index.php?page=2, mysite.com/index.php?page=3 and so on. I would to remove 'index.php?page=' from each one.

Comment: First, someone else did write an answer for you, so maybe that's what you want! However I do not think this is a proper approach. All you need to do is read about a simple php string manipulation functions, those should take you maybe 15 to 30 minutes to learn and figure out. This would produce a much simple code to both write and maintaine and will make your life much much much easier.